# How to Remove the spaces between the values of element in xslt

Tags: xslt

```html
Input:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Customer>
  <FName>Vijender Reddy</FName>
  <Address>Hyderabad        </Address>
  <Id>122 2222</Id>
</Customer>
```

```html
Output:
<Customer>
  <FName>VijenderReddy</FName>
  <Address>Hyderabad</Address>
  <Id>1222222</Id>
</Customer>
```

we need to remove the spaces in the all elements values.

Comment: Is there any language you want this implemented with?Also, not really important, but the formatting tags you used are for Javascript & HTML, not XML

Answer (score 1):

That is easy even in XSLT 1.0 as `translate(., ' ', '')` will remove all spaces so write two templates, the first one being the identity transformation template copying unchanged what does not need change and the second doing the translate:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Customer/*[not(*)]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="translate(., ' ', '')"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Online at http://xsltransform.net/pPzifpA.

Comment: Thanks..!  It is working fine. Can You Please explain [not(*)] filter statement.

Comment: `Customer/*` selects all child elements of the `Customer` element, I added the predicate `Customer/*[not(*)]` to apply the transformation only to child elements that don't have any child elements of their own. Your sample did not show any such elements but often there are further such elements, and doing a string operation like `translate` if there are child elements would strip them.

Comment: Martin Can you plese help me in below issue. Instead of removing spaces between the words in the element values i need to remove only  trailing and leading spaces in the element values.                                                        Input: <FName>    Vijender Reddy    </FName>                                               Need Output like: <FName>Vijender Reddy</FName>

Comment: Check whether using `normalize-space()` instead of `translate(., ' ', '')` suffices, it will remove leading and trailing white space but also collapse any sequences of white space between words to a single space. If that does not help, then ask a new question.